# How to pause SFTP uploads using Java JSch library?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am editing a Java application that uses the com.jcraft.jsch library to perform SFTP uploads using `channel.put()` where `channel` is an instance of [ChannelSftp](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html).

What I'm trying to do is add a user control that allows the upload to be paused and resumed.

I've seen that the com.jscape.inet.sftp library has a [Sftp](http://files.jscape.com/sftp/docs/javadoc/com/jscape/inet/sftp/Sftp.html) class which has methods `interrupt()` and `resumeUpload()` which look like they will do what I need.

However I don't want to rewrite the upload functionality of the application if I can help it. Is there any way I can easily get the current implementation to pause and resume at will?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the `ChannelSftp` while it's in the paused state? Should the channel remain open? How about the SSH session? Should it be closed or remain open?

Comment: @Kenster good question. I definitely want the session to remain open, and I suppose the channel too. That way the user can quickly unpause the upload. I would need to close any open connections when the application exits, whether the user has paused a transfer or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the overload of the `ChannelSftp.put` method that takes a source and destination path. You have no control there in exchange for simplicity.

---

The best solution is to use the overload of the `put` that takes a destination path only and returns the `OutputStream`.

```
public OutputStream put(String dst) throws SftpException
```

Then you feed data to the returned stream as you like, pausing when you need.

---

Simpler (but ugly imho) solution would be to use the overload that takes source and destination path and the [`SftpProgressMonitor` interface](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpProgressMonitor.html).

```
public void put(String src, String dst, 
                SftpProgressMonitor monitor) throws SftpException
```

You can then abuse it by implementing the [`SftpProgressMonitor.count` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpProgressMonitor.html#count-long-) to block, when you need to pause the transfer.

Comment: You're correct that I am using `public void put(InputStream src, String dst, SftpProgressMonitor monitor, int mode) throws SftpException`  so I already have a `SftpProgressMonitor` to abuse. Thanks for providing various suggestions, you have given me ideas to explore where I was previously stuck. I will try these out and then come back :)